# Accurate automated closed captioning

Tags: subtitles, closed-captioning

I have been looking into automated closed captioning and the accuracy of the services found so far is poor.

I am looking to caption a number of 1hour + presentation recordings so manual captions isn't a feasible option.

Are there any worth while automated services out there??

Comment: Why do you say manual captioning isn't an option? There are some good, affordable captioning services out there. You get much better results with manual captioning.

Comment: Where I work we use 3playmedia. Accurate enough, and way cheaper than if any of us did it.

Answer (score 1):

YouTube's automated closed captions are actually getting better and better (and it's free!). Even if you don't use the automated (speech-to-text) captions in YouTube, it has a neat tool that pauses while you type a transcript (or lets you upload a transcript) and then automatically adjusts all the timings. You can find it in the Closed Captions section of any video you've uploaded.